# sed - delete only words with vowels

Tags: regex, bash, sed, substitution

I am trying to delete all words that start with a vowel as per below. The sed command I have is only deleting the first word if it has a vowel, not any others. I thought the boundary marker below and using the `g` would capture all words but it is not doing it. How do I get it to get all words with vowels ?

```
echo "Always take a Big Apple " | sed -r 's/\b^[AEIOUaeiou]\w*//g'
```

Comment: Related: [sed - print words that start with a vowel only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429901/sed-print-words-that-start-with-a-vowel-only)

Answer (score 5):

Remove `^`

```
sed -r 's/\b[AEIOUaeiou]\w*//g'
```

you don't need to anchor it to the beginning of line, enough that you request it to be on the word boundary.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I thought the ^ had to be in to get all words "starting" with a vowel - obviously not then

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Always take a Big Apple " | sed -r 's/\b[AEIOUaeiou]\w*//g'
```

Comment: thanks ...how do you reverse this to print only print words that DO start with a vowel then ?  I have tried putting in ! above but it does not work but I thought that would just invert the rule above ?

Comment: @frodo: `sed -r 's/\b[^AEIOUaeiou]\w*//g'`

Answer (score 1):

This GNU sed solution might work for you:

```
echo "Always take a Big Apple " | sed 's/\<[aeiou]\w*//Ig'
```