# sed - print words that start with a vowel only

Tags: bash, sed

how do you reverse this sed to print only print words that DO START with a vowel? I have tried putting in ! in the sed command below but it does not work - I thought that would just invert the rule above ?

```
echo "Always take a Big Apple " | sed -r 's/\b[AEIOUaeiou]\w*//g'
```

Comment: Related: [sed - delete only words with vowels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429049/sed-delete-only-words-with-vowels)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a `^` and not `!`:

```
$ echo "Always take a Big Apple " | sed -r 's/\b[^AEIOU ]\w*//ig' 
Always  a  Apple
```

Comment: +1 for providing a revised version that matches the 'a' as well.

Comment: Thanks razlebe - this is what I intended - why do you have to leave a space in [^AEIOU ] between the U and ] - i dont understand that ?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r 's/\b[^AEIOUaeiou[:space:]]\w*\b//g'
```

Comment: Thanks Michael but why why do you need to put in space ?

Comment: Because there are two lines boundaries - the one that starts the word and the one that ends it.

Answer (score 1):

The character you're looking for to negate the character class is `^`, not `!`:

```
echo "Always take a Big Apple " | sed -r 's/\b[^AEIOUaeiou]\w*//g'
```

However, note that your regex as is will not match the `a` in `a Big Apple` - is that what you intended?